# google plus api: get access token and user details from code in php

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm using google server side flow, the link is
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow .

I'm struct with the step 8, actually I dont know how to get the access token from code.

I got the code after authentication, and I sent that code to the server and my server code is

```
require_once '../google/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../google/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Login with Google+');
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
$code = $_POST['code'];
$client->authenticate($code);

$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

return $token;
```

Now I'm getting internal server error(500).

Can anyone pls help to fix this.

Comment: Your server logs should have an error message that says what's causing the 500 error.